# XCode Navigator cannot reaarange files

Tags: xcode, file

Got an irritating issue with xcode 5.1

I have lost the ability to rearrange files and groups within the xcode project. If I try to move anything I get no visual feedback and file returns to original position when dropped.

It works ok on other projects but I have done something to this particular project, and cannot seem to undo the problem...closed re-opened project/xcode etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I asked the question, I found the answer myself (after getting frustrated for hours).

The problem is I had the letter 'e' in the file filter box at the bottom of the navigator. So, obviously, I am prevented from rearranging!

....for info purposes!